# Rails 4 running in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, passenger

I'm using Passenger to run my app with apache, and everything works fine if I use routes.

However, any manual routes I add for `'get /url' => 'controller#action'` do not seem to work.

If I use `scope "#{Rails.application.config.action_controller.relative_url_root}" do`, then `link_for` does not throw errors but trying to access the actual url results in no route found.

1.) How do I setup `rails s` to run in a subdirectory off localhost so I can test routes in the same manner as my deployed servers

2.) How do I configure routes to work with `relative_url_root`?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the config option is still an outstanding bug in Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5122

Passenger does have some instructions for deploying to subdirectories: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri

But if you don't run Passenger on your local, I would recommend using native namespacing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing.  I updated the global namespace in my app's routes.rb file and that fixed it for me.  It's not the cleanest but it works.  I just make sure not to commit those changes to the repo.